# How do I save and version brew packages?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am used to installing packages and libraries via tools like npm, pip, and gem. These tools allow me to track the installed packages in some form or another (package.json, requirements.txt, or a Gemfile). This can then be checked into a repo and versioned.

I have a dotfiles repo on Github that I like to use as way to version control my machine configuration and I was wondering if there was a way to version control installed brew packages? If so how is this done? Something like `brew install --save` is what I am hoping for. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re looking for [Homebrew Bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle#brew-bundle).

It lets you keep track of installed formulae (packages) in a `Brewfile`.

You can then dump all the installed formulae in it with `brew bundle dump`, install all formulae from a bundle with `brew bundle`, and remove all installed formulae *that aren’t listed in the bundle* with `brew bundle cleanup`.

The syntax is very similar to [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)’s, so it’s easy to edit the file by yourself.

It support both local Brewfiles (e.g. one per project) and a global one (`~/.Brewfile`).

Install it with:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/bundle
```

Comment: Note, though, that bundle doesn't support specifying versions of packages because Homebrew doesn't support installing arbitrary versions of packages. Since Homebrew formulas are stored in a git repository, you could check out a particular revision of Homebrew before running `brew bundle`, to use the newest formulas available at that point in git history.

Comment: @TimSmith Or you could use formulae from `homebrew/versions` but it doesn’t contain everything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way for any *nix based system:

```
#create list of installed packages
brew list | xargs -L1 > Brewfile
# install packages
cat Brewfile | xargs brew
```

This is not as sophisticated as [Homebrew bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle#brew-bundle) but it does the job if you're in a hurry.